# subtract functions with type real in ml

Tags: sml, ml

I'm trying to subtract two functions(both with type real) in moscow ml. It then says "Overloaded - cannot be applied to arguments of type real -> real. So how should I write the function?

```
fun CircleArea  x = x*x*Math.pi

fun SquareArea x:real = 4*x*x

fun Area x = SquareArea - CircleArea
```

Answer (score 5):

You probably don't actually want to subtract one function from another, but the return values of those functions once they are applied. You could achieve this in the following way:

```
fun Area x = (SquareArea x) - (CircleArea x)
```

The parentheses are not mandatory, since function application (i.e. the space between `SquareArea` and `x`) binds tighter than any binary operator, including `-`.

You should consider using the following naming convention in ML: Regular functions have a lowercase starting symbol, while value constructors for algebraic types have uppercase starting symbols. For example:

```
fun area x = squareArea x - circleArea x
```

But:

```
datatype shape = Square of int * int
               | Circle of int
```

Answer (score 2):

Subtraction of functions like we have in mathematics isn't provided as a built-in operator. You can, however, define your own.

Mathematically speaking, we define

```
(f - g)(x) = f(x) - g(x)
```

We can replicate this definition in SML as follows:

```
infix 5 --
fun f -- g = fn x => f x - g x
```

What this does is produce an operator, `--`, such that `f -- g` produces the function corresponding to `fn x => f x - g x`, i.e. the function that given an `x` calculates `f x - g x`.

Note, due to the type-ambiguity in the `-` operator, it'll default to let you subtract `'a -> int` functions. In your case you'll want to subtract `'a -> real` functions, so you'll need a slight modification:

```
infix 5 --
fun f -- g = fn x => f x - g x : real
```

If you use this `--`-operator, you will be able to define your `Area` function like so:

```
val area = squareArea -- circleArea;
```

(I took the liberty of making the first letter of function names lowercase, to match the SML naming conventions.)